# converting jQuery's siblings function to vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on converting jQuery to vanilla Javascript and facing a problem of siblings.

Here is my code:

```
   const right = document.querySelector('.right');
   const bullets = document.getElementsByClassName('bullets')
   right.addEventListener('click', function(){
    const has = document.querySelector('.swiper-pagination-bullet-active').getAttribute('aria-label');
    const idx = Number(has.substr(12,1))-1;
```

What I want to do is
if one of bullets has 'active' class, the others cannot take siblings.
so wrote code like this

```
   bullets[idx].classList.add('active');
    let siblings = bullets.parentElement.children;
    for(let sib of siblings) {
        sib.classList.remove('active')
      }
   });
```

`bullets[idx].classList.add('active');` is working, but the below codes are now working. Could anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: First remove the `.active` class (on all of them), then set it on the "active bullet"

Comment: `bullets` is a list of elements. There's no `parentElement` property for a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `siblings()` doesn't put the element you call it on in the list. Your code does, b/c `children` includes all children. `bullets.parentElement` doesn't work, `bullets` is list not element. For siblings of `bullets[idx]` do:

```
bullets[idx].classList.add('active')
for(let sib of bullets[idx].parentElement.children) {
  if (sib !== bullets[idx]) {
    sib.classList.remove('active')
  }
}
```

Or remove class from all children before add to `bullet[idx]`.